# Django get_comment_list isn't returning the comments

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-comments

I am using Django's comments framework to manage comments in my website. I have  custom comment model and form that extends Django's, as following:

Model:

```
class FTComment(Comment):
    upvotes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    downvotes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Form:

```
class FTCommentForm(CommentForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(required=True)

    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        # Use the data of the superclass, and remove extra fields
        return dict(
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.target_object),
            object_pk    = force_unicode(self.target_object._get_pk_val()),
            comment      = self.cleaned_data["comment"],
            submit_date  = datetime.datetime.now(),
            site_id      = settings.SITE_ID,
            is_public    = True,
            is_removed   = False,
        )

FTCommentForm.base_fields.pop('url')
FTCommentForm.base_fields.pop('email')
FTCommentForm.base_fields.pop('name')
```

The comment form works fine, and browsing the database data in the SQLite Database Browser I can find it there:

[image: SQLite Database Browser]

So, why can't I get the list of comments? Is there something I'm missing? Here's the template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load comments %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/comment.css" />

<p>
    <strong>{% trans "Comments" %}</strong>
</p>

<div class="comment_box">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% render_comment_form for obj %}
    {% else %}
        <p>Please <a href="/login">log in</a> to leave a comment.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% get_comment_count for obj as count %}
    <p>Count: {{ count }}</p>
    {% get_comment_list for obj as comments %}
    {% for comment in comments %}
        {{ comment.comment }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`count` returns 0, although there are 2 comments for this object in the database, and the `for` loop renders nothing.

A help with this would be hugely appreciated.

**Edit: View added**

Here's the view of this case in particular:

```
def show_detail(request, img_id):
    img = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=img_id)
    img.views += 1
    img.save()

    try:
        referer = Referer()
        referer.referer_url = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        referer.object = img
        referer.save()
    except KeyError:
        pass

    return render(request, "img/show_detail.html", {'img': img})
```

**Edit 2:**

I'm sorry, I should have explained. The templates which renders the comments is in a different file so it can be used by other pages/templates. The reference to the object is passed like this: `{% include "comment/main.html" with obj=img %}` to this template.

Comment: Can you include your view as well?

Comment: Yes, one second. Although the view does not contain any code from the comments framework (if I understood the documentation correctly, I don't need to have any).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `obj` that you are referring to in `{% get_comment_list for obj as comments %}` is not in your template context.

If your comments are on the Image model, then you should change all your references to `obj` in your template code, to `img`, because that is the key you are giving it in your template context (from `return render(request, "img/show_detail.html", {'img': img})`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explained. The templates which renders the comments is in a different file so it can be used by other pages/templates. The reference to the object is passed like this: `{% include "comment/main.html" with obj=img %}` to this template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [comments template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#comment-template-tags) `{% load_comments %}` in you template. Then you can access the comments context.

Comment: Thanks, but it is included, I cut it to make the code smaller here. It is included here as well now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my custom form wasn't referencing my custom model, but Django's stock model, AND, the tag `get_comment_list` as well as `get_comment_count` was referencing my custom model, as defined in my comments app `__init__.py`:

```
def get_model():
    return FTComment

def get_form():
    return FTCommentForm
```

So, the form was saving the comment as a Django comment object, but the template tag was *trying* to fetch my custom comment object, which was empty in the database.

The solution was to define a `get_comment_model` method in the custom form as explained [in the Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/comments/custom/).

The final form of the form, with the added fields `upvotes` and `downvotes` from the custom model is like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode

from fingertools.comment.models import FTComment


class FTCommentForm(CommentForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(required=True)
    
    def get_comment_model(self):
        return FTComment
    
    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        # Use the data of the superclass, and remove extra fields
        return dict(
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.target_object),
            object_pk    = force_unicode(self.target_object._get_pk_val()),
            comment      = self.cleaned_data["comment"],
            submit_date  = datetime.datetime.now(),
            site_id      = settings.SITE_ID,
            is_public    = True,
            is_removed   = False,
            upvotes      = 0,
            downvotes    = 0,
        )
    
FTCommentForm.base_fields.pop('url')
FTCommentForm.base_fields.pop('email')
FTCommentForm.base_fields.pop('name')
```